# How to trigger animation for a specific item and not all item in a list

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to animate the clicked only without animating the rest

```
@Component({
  selector: \\\\\
  templateUrl: \\\\

animations: [
 trigger('showFull', [
   state('shrink', style({
     height: '50px'
   })),
   state('expand', style ({
     height: '*'
   })),
   transition('shrink <=> expand', animate('300ms ease-in'))
 ])
]
})
///

export class myComp {
    state: string = 'shrink';

}

toggleExpansion(){
    this.state = (this.state === 'shrink' ? 'expand' : 'shrink');  
}
```

.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <ion-item [@showFull]="state" (click)="toggleExpansion()">
     {{item.description}}
   </ion-item>
</div>
```

how/what to pass to the function so that `state` doesn't change for all the listed items.

On a side problem, How to improve the animation code to collapse and expand

[image]

the above is when the state is `expand`

[image]

and this when state is `shrink` and it can be noticed that the start of the paragraph is also collapsed/covered... How to animate to expand and collapse from&to a specific point !

Comment: you would need to have state for each item in the list.

Comment: whats the ideal solution here, since my list of items are from a server side and length would be unknown, also user would add and delete these items.. I am doing this to truncate and show a paragraph

Comment: you can add a property `state` in the item when you get the object from server side..

Comment: so I append on each item `state` with the value of `shrink` and then just do this `[@showFull]="item.state" (click)="toggleExpansion(item.state)"` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property state in the item when you get the object from server side.

```
this.items.forEach(item => item.state = "shrink");
```

In your html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <ion-item [@showFull]="item.state" (click)="toggleExpansion(item)">
     {{item.description}}
   </ion-item>
</div>
```

Finally in the component,

```
toggleExpansion(item:any){
    item.state = (item.state === 'shrink' ? 'expand' : 'shrink');  
}
```

Comment: my items are list of objects, thats why I guess I am receiving error on `forEach` returning undefined

Comment: I gave foreach as an example.. it depends on where you are setting the array..just set this property as well

Comment: thanx bro, any suggestion regarding the animation itself

Comment: you might want to set some sort of truncated value in shrink while toggling..maybe with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`